# Context Initialization Failure -- BeanCreationNotAllowedException

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, cxf

The Spring Context of my application is failing to initialize. Can anyone help me understand why it is failing and how to fix it?

Below are the warning & error messages I'm getting:

> [WARN] Invocation of destroy method 'shutdown' failed on bean with
>   name 'cxf'
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Singleton bean
>   creation not allowed while the singletons of this factory are in
>   destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy
>   method implementation!)
>
> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader
>   [ERROR] Context initialization failed

```xml
<bean id="cxf" class="org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusImpl" destroy-method="shutdown"/>
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
       <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="${persistence.unit}"/>
       <property name="dataSource" ref="pooledDs"/>
       <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
           <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
               <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
               <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
               <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
           </bean>
       </property>    
</bean>
```

Comment: Can you post your xml configuration?  Or, if you are using Annotation configuration, post the class that is identified by the name 'cfx' and 'entityManagerFactory'.

Comment: Are there any errors leading up to this warning?

Comment: @AaronSheffey: No, there are no errors leading up to the warning.

Answer (score 4):

The CXF website doesn't include the `destroy-method` call in its example configurations, so it seems like this is a misconfiguration.  See this page for details: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html.

I also found a bug tracker for this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-2164.  It appears that the destroy method was not implicitly being called in earlier versions of CXF, but that has been fixed in v2.2.11.

So, my suggestion would be to get up to at least that version and just have `<bean id="cxf" class="org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusImpl" />` in your config.

Comment: I upgraded from version 2.3.2 to 2.4.2 and that resolved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @kin1 So post your solution as an answer and accept it, please. In this way people will see immediately that the question is solved and doesn't need a solution anymore. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had same problem with version 2.5.0, but that was my fault.

I had wrong bean in context.

In detail: I had Spring MVC Controller (named OrderController) annotated with `@Controller` without defined name (annotation driven). On the other CXF requires xml configuration AFAIK, so I named bean using java configuration (using `@Bean`) as `orderController` and somehow when cxf was initialized Spring used this wrong MVC controller and it failed on error listed above.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf': Singleton bean creation not allowed while the singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)